# Merging multiple objects with list fields

Tags: java, merge

I am working with objects that have as their properties lists of strings:

```
public class MyObjectOne {
     private List<String> listOne;
     private List<String> listTwo;
     private MyObjectTwo myObjectTwo;
}

public class MyObjectTwo {
     private List<String> listOne;
     private List<String> listTwo;
}
```

I want to merge multiple MyObjectOne objects,
in such a way that I get one new object where all the lists are merged, including the ones in the nested objects MyObjectTwo.

I realise there are probably better ways to structure the program so that I don't have to to this, but I'm stuck with this  code.

Is there any way to achieve this without having to explicitly write mappers for the objects? In practice each object has 10+ of these List properties and there are multiple nested objects, so writing it all out would be a huge pain.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use interface, which can return all lists to be merged and all the Nested Objects.
Like this one:

```
interface Mergable {
    List<List<String>> getAllLists();

    List<Mergable> getAllNestedObjects();
}

class MyObjectOne implements Mergable {
    private List<String> listOne;
    private List<String> listTwo;
    private MyObjectTwo myObjectTwo;

    @Override
    public List<List<String>> getAllLists() {
        return Stream.of(listOne, listTwo).collect(toList());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Mergable> getAllNestedObjects() {
        return Stream.of(myObjectTwo).collect(toList());
    }
}

class MyObjectTwo implements Mergable {
    private List<String> listOne;
    private List<String> listTwo;

    @Override
    public List<List<String>> getAllLists() {
        return Stream.of(listOne, listTwo).collect(toList());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Mergable> getAllNestedObjects() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

And then via recursion merge all of them into List or wherever you were going to store it.

Answer (score 0):

Add following method to `MyObjectOne` and getter for `listOne` and `listTwo` to `MyObjectTwo` class. BTW you should have tried this yourself first.

```
public List<String> merge(){
    List<String> result = new ArrayList();
    result.addAll(listOne);
    result.addAll(listTwo);
    result.addAll(myObjectTwo.getListOne());
    result.addAll(myObjectTwo.getListTwo());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't want one big list, I want a new object where the listOne fields are all merged into the listOne property, all the listTwo fields into the listTwo property, etc. Also, I should have probably mentioned, I can not edit the objects themselves.

Comment: @Spacejockey Please edit the question then since it is quite unclear that this is a requirement.